# Tags in the Zend Dojo Form

Tags: zend-framework

I would like to get the tag same as in this stackoverflow's form. My form is the zend dojo form and I am having problem in creating the concept of tag in the form. The tag should be autocomplete in the input box when user inputs value and when the there is space between the word it system should take as the different value.So can anyone help me in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest :

- Learning how to make your own widget : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/writingWidgets.html
- Taking some inspiration in this Jquery example : http://jcesar.artelogico.com/jquery-tagselector/
- Learning about dijit.InlineEditBox : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/InlineEditBox.html
- Learning about dijit.form.FilteringSelect : http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect

After that, you can do your own widget. You may start with a template like this (see link 1 for how to define widget templates) :

```
<div>
    <div class="${baseClass}" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"></div>
</div>
```

And your widget javascript code could look like this (using dojo 1.7) :

```
define("ps/Tag", 
["dojo/_base/declare", 
 "dijit/_WidgetBase", 
 "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
 "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
 "dojo/text!ps/templates/Tag.html",
 "dijit/InlineEditBox",
 "dijit/form/FilteringSelect"
 ], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template, InlineEditBox, FilteringSelect) {

declare("ps.Tag", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

    baseClass : "tag",

    templateString : template,

    store : null,

    searchAttr : null,

    value : null,

    postCreate : function() {
        var widget = this;
        eb = new InlineEditBox({
            editor: "dijit.form.FilteringSelect",
            editorParams : {
                store : widget.store,
                searchAttr: widget.searchAttr,
                value : widget.value
            },
            autoSave: true
        }, this.containerNode);
    }
});
return ps.Tag;
```

});

I'll leave the css to you (you can find it in the example of link 2 and tweak it with firebug).

You can then use your widget like this, in your html :

```
var stateStore = new Memory({
                    data: [
                        {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
                        {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
                        {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
                        {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
                        {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
                        {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
                        {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
                        {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
                        {name:"California", id:"CA"},
                        {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
                        {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
                        {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
                    ]
                });
                var tag = new Tag({store : stateStore, searchAttr : "name", value : "CA"});
                dojo.place(tag.domNode, "yourTagContainerDivId", "last");
```

I hope it helps.